# Getting Volume Encryption Status

Tags: swift, encryption

I'm trying to determine if all or any of the volumes on macOS are encrypted. It seems like this code should work but is not correctly getting the status. Despite the volume being encrypted the var "ifEncrypted" is false and the call to add it to the encryptedVolumes array is never called.

```
var encryptedVolumes = [Any]()

for vol in internalVolumes {
   let url = vol
   let volumeEncryptedKey = try? url.resourceValues(forKeys: [.volumeIsEncryptedKey])
   let isEncrypted:Bool = (volumeEncryptedKey?.volumeIsEncrypted)!
   if isEncrypted {
      encryptedVolumes.append(url)
   }
}
```

Comment: Can you update your question with more details, specifically expected vs actual results?

Comment: Unrelated to your issue, but: to avoid crashes when weird cases pop up, use `?? false` instead of `!` to unwrap the optional Boolean value.

Comment: That change triggers an IDE error: Value of optional type 'Bool?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?

Comment: @jbrown94305 You must have made a typo somewhere. If you type it as `let isEncrypted = volumeEncryptedKey?.volumeIsEncrypted ?? false` it will compile (and be a lot safer).